# Copy value from one subgrid another subgrid in Dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm

How to copy records in subgrid one page to another page  subgrid with same entity. I have one opportunity form  in this form I created one button in this click it will open same opportunity from I want to copy data from first opportunity page to other page I copied all textbox, dropdown, lookup values I used querystring this value copied. I am stuck with subgrid data copy from first page to other page.

I try to pass object in querystring it insert in first page subgrid:

```js
if(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('cts_originalsalespersonid').getValue() == null)
{
var OriginalOwnerId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('ownerid').getValue()[0].id;
var OriginalOwnerName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('ownerid').getValue()[0].name;
}
else
{
var OriginalOwnerId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('cts_originalsalespersonid').getValue()[0].id;
var OriginalOwnerName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('cts_originalsalespersonid').getValue()[0].name;
}

extraqs += '&cts_originalsalespersonid=' + OriginalOwnerId;
extraqs += '&cts_originalsalespersonidname=' + OriginalOwnerName;

var opid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var opName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
    
var queryOpt = {
        entityName: "cts_lineitem",
        attributes: ["cts_opportunityid"],
        values: [opid,],
        columnSet: ["rx_totalquantity", "cts_itemid","cts_itemnumber"]
    };
var fetchedLineItem = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.QueryByAttribute(queryOpt);

var xVals = fetchedLineItem.map(function (obj) { return obj.attributes; });
var xNames = xVals.map(function (obj) { return obj.cts_itemnumber; });
  
for (var i = 0; i < xVals.length; i++) 
{
var addAddresses = new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity("cts_lineitem");
addAddresses.attributes["cts_opportunityid"] = { id: opid, logicalName: "opportunity", type: "EntityReference" };
addAddresses.attributes["rx_totalquantity"] = xVal[i].rx_totalquantity;
addAddresses.attributes["cts_itemid"] = xVals[i].cts_itemid;
addAddresses.attributes["cts_itemnumber"] = xVals[i].cts_itemnumber;

addAddresses.attributes["cts_lineitemid "] = xVals[i].cts_lineitemid ;
addResponse = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(addAddresses);
}

window.open('/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=' + encodeURIComponent(extraqs), '_blank');
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emjam.png this is main page here I put one button
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kFL3.png  this main opportunity has subgrid
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4vxq.png  here  this page I need to copy data in subgrid

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requierement correct, you need to copy Opportunity record with it's all fields and it's subrecords as well. With subrecords I mean all the linked Record (subgrid)

I would like to suggest slightly different (better in my sense).

There are 2 ways you can perform your this.

1. [Dynamics 365 workflow tools, clone of record.](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools/blob/master/docs/Clone%20Record.md)
2. [Perform copy of opp on server side rather than client side.](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/184794/copy-records-through-plugin?pifragment-97030=1)

When I mean server side I mean Plugin.
You have a button, on click of this button run a Action (custom)

When this action is run (plugin) perform copying of records with subgrid records. This is more stable and easy way and this will perform almost all the time. In this way you could create copy of record bullet proof.